# Showing Outlook VSTO Formregion on system administrator undeliverable message item

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a pretty specific problem, maybe some of you have an idea..

I'm making a VSTO AddIn for outlook, and I managed to show a formregion - first with registry entries, than I figured it out, that I can define with the "Form region Wizard" - on specific Items (like Appointment, Meeting item etc.) but I cannot find a way to show the formregion on undeliverable message item, sent by System Administrator.

Any Suggestions? Which Item could it be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item in Outlook has a message class associated with it. In your scenario you deal with a [ReportItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.reportitem). Here is what MSDN states for that object:

> The ReportItem object is similar to a MailItem object, and it contains a report (usually the non-delivery report) or error message from the mail transport system. Unlike other Microsoft Outlook objects, you cannot create this object. Report items are created automatically when any report or error in general is received from the mail transport system.

And the form region is usually associated with a particular message class. The report item has the `REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR` string for the message class. It seems you just need to specify the right message class for your form region.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer!

Second: I found out already, that the Item what I'm looking for is the ReportItem, but the problem is, that when I create a FormRegion, I have to determine on which MailItem types should the FormRegion appear.

I can specify custom Item types, but the Wizard doesn't accept the `REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR`.

[Screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/JUehEXj.png)

Comment: Any idea? (Thanks again, with the `REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR` is at least a new clue where to start.)

Comment: Ok, if i add a registry entry for `REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR` it appears. It's just a bit inconvinient, to add custom registry entries. Do you have idea, how to force the wizzard to accept it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to input that message class as a custom in the wizard?